# Rounding in Java

Tags: java, apache-commons

I think you have seen in the shopping malls, they deduct or add some amount to your total purchase amount like,

- If your total purchase is 30.01, Round as 30.00
- If your total purchase is 30.03, Round as 30.05.
- If your total purchase is 30.07, Round as 30.05.
- If your total purchase is 30.08, Round as 30.10.

I know rounding and floor and ceil functions in Java. But how can I acheive the above things?
Is there any default function or utils available?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag as so.

Comment: And what did you find when your entered `java float round` into that search box up on the top right? Five thousand hits is what I got, surely you could find _something_ in that list to suit :-)

Comment: We really need a "author did no research at all and abuses SO as their personal google" close kind...

Comment: Hi paxdiablo, Voo, i have update my query,if you can please try to find the solution.I have put the question for somewhat reduce the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

First of all when you manipulate price in the retail environment (like malls) you should use integer or long and not float or double, because the number is always with 2 decimal and the best way to handle total in retail is with integer values.

So for example :

```
30.01f ---> 3001
30.03f ---> 3003
```

And so on ... Doing that we have simplified a lot the way of handling price values.
After that you can easily create your own **price rounding algorithm**.

Here a sample round price function that should do exactly what you want :

```
public static int roundPrice(int price) {
        String strPrice = String.valueOf(price);
        int len = strPrice.length();
        int lastDigit = Integer.valueOf( strPrice.substring(len -1) );
        int toAdd = -lastDigit;

        if(lastDigit > 7)
            toAdd = 10 - lastDigit;
        else if(lastDigit > 2)
            toAdd = 5 - lastDigit;

        return price + toAdd;
    }
```

And here's an example of how you can use it :

```
public static void main(String[] ars) {

        int[] nums = { 3001, 3003, 3007, 3008 };

        for(int n : nums) {
            System.out.println(roundPrice(n));
        }
    }
```

I don't know why some users have commented your question as it is trivial question, and as if in this forum there are several others response that explain what you want ... 
I can't even figure out why you got -5 for this question ... Mysteries of StackOverflow !

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). Example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for: [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/text/DecimalFormat.html) look for `RoundingMode`